# DateTime variable set equal to itself in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Is there any reason why someone would set a DateTime variable equal to itself in Visual Basic like dtLocDate is in the code below?

```
Function ShouldBillingStart(ByVal sTheBillingType As String, _
  ByRef bStartIt As Boolean, _
  ByVal dtBillPeriod As DateTime) As Boolean

    Dim bLocResult As Boolean
    Dim dtFirstOfMonth As DateTime
    Dim dtLocDate As DateTime

    bLocResult = True
    bStartIt = True
    If bLocResult = True Then
        If CInt(sTheBillingType) = gTheMasterPriceList.PricingType.PRICING_TYPE_DISCOUNTED Then
            dtLocDate = dtLocDate
            dtFirstOfMonth = CDate(Year(dtLocDate) & "/" & Month(dtLocDate) & "/1")
            'add a month
            dtFirstOfMonth = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, dtFirstOfMonth)
            If Now < dtFirstOfMonth Then
                bStartIt = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ShouldBillingStart = bLocResult
End Function
```

Comment: possibly the code originally set it to something and rather than remove the line, they did that to remember where it was in case they needed to set it back.  Alternatively it could be a Do-Nothing line for setting a breakpoint.  It does nothing though

Comment: What is a `DateTime` here anyway?  Some .Net class being used via inter-clop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.  This is just referencing itself.  The Dim statement instantiates the Date object.  Self referencing it wouldn't create the object though, nor set a default value.

This appears to serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, no reason at all. For example:

```
Dim This as String

This = "that"
This = This
```

Waste of time & resources...